# Windows 10 Development: How to bind two different data types to ListView?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, data-binding, windows-10-universal

So, I am trying to bind a LinkedList of string type, Tasks, to the Content property of checkboxes in a ListView. At the same time, I want to bind a LinkedList of Boolean type, IsCompleted, to the IsChecked property of checkboxes in the ListView. I am able to do either one but not both.
Here are my codes:
XAML

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                           <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsCompleted}" Content="{Binding}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

C#

```
public sealed partial class AddPage : Page
{
private Projects project = new Projects();
this.DataContext = project;
}
```

The Data Model:

```
public class Projects
{
public LinkedList<string> Tasks { get; set; }
public LinkedList<bool> IsCompleted { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried not using ItemsSource for ListView and rely on the this.DataContext or myListView.DataContext in C# together with {Binding Tasks} for Content and {Binding IsCompleted} for IsChecked. But nothing is shown without the ItemsSource. I also tried specifying the Binding path to no avail. I would gladly appreciate any help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, we can see that CheckBox is the child of the ListView as following:
[image]

So it will mean that one ListViewItem will have only one CheckBox, in this way we can not bind a LinkedList(**IsCompleted**) to the CheckBox, we can only bind a single value for every CheckBox.

Besides, the LinkedList or others collections can only be used for the [ItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.aspx): such as ListView,ListBox,GridView and so on.

In order to bind two different data types to the ListView, please try to modify your code to let the **Tasks and IsCompleted** use the **string/bool** data type instead of the **LinkedList** Collection, after that we can bind the LinkedList collection which contains the class object for the Tasks and IsCompleted to the ListView.

For more information, please check the following code:

XAML Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" ItemsSource="{Binding NewProject}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsCompleted}" Content="{Binding Tasks}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

CS code:

```
public class Projects
{
    public string Tasks { get; set; }
    public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public LinkedList<Projects> NewProject { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        NewProject = new LinkedList<Projects>();
        NewProject.AddLast(new Projects() {Tasks="Task1",IsCompleted=true});
        NewProject.AddLast(new Projects() { Tasks = "Task2", IsCompleted = false });
        NewProject.AddLast(new Projects() { Tasks = "Task3", IsCompleted = true });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

}

The result:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, my Projects class also contain other properties such as string Title. What I wish to accomplish is for a user to tap on the Project title on the main page (data binding with title) and the information about that particular project is pulled out and shown in another page. However, I want to be able to store and show the Tasks which is a collection of items in one instance of project class. How am I able to do that??

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response but I have solved my own problem. It is my mistake that I did not search for solutions at MSDN properly. I found my solution that worked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/how-to-bind-to-hierarchical-data-and-create-a-master-details-view